# How to handle whitespace in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

Input File

```
      name;x1;x2
    jon,doe;10;20
    sam,smith;11;21
```

This is what i have tried so far

```
awk 'BEGIN {print "name\tx1\tx2\tAvg"} {s+=$2} {k+=$3} {print $1,"\t",$2,"\t",$3,"\t",($2+$3)/2} END {print s/2,k/2}' input.txt
```

I am trying to find the average of rows and columns from an input file but at the end i am getting one zero that i don't need and i believe that is due to white space. Can someone help me how to handle white space here ?

The expected output should be :

```
name;x1;x2 Average 
jon,doe;10;20 15
sam,smith;11;21 16
Average 10.5 20.5
```

Comment: What is the expected output for this file?

Comment: @ReutSharabani the expected output should be average of rows and columns.

Comment: @ReutSharabani why is it down voted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default input field separator for awk is whitespace.  That doesn't work for your file where the field separator is a semicolon.  To fix that, use the `-F\;` option.  With a few other minor changes, try:

```
$ awk -F';' '{sub(/^ +/,"");} NR==1 {print $0, "Avg";next} {s+=$2} {k+=$3} {print $0,($2+$3)/2} END {print "Ave",s/(NR-1),k/(NR-1)}' OFS='\t' input.txt
name;x1;x2      Avg
jon,doe;10;20   15
sam,smith;11;21 16
Ave     10.5    20.5
```

The sample output in the question and as above has a mix of semicolons and whitespace for field separators.  If you want to consistently use semicolons:

```
$ awk -F';' '{sub(/^ +/,"");} NR==1 {print $0, "Avg";next} {s+=$2} {k+=$3} {print $0,($2+$3)/2} END {print "Ave",s/(NR-1),k/(NR-1)}' OFS=';' input.txt
name;x1;x2;Avg
jon,doe;10;20;15
sam,smith;11;21;16
Ave;10.5;20.5
```

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for. I have corrected above table as u mentioned. (11+21)/2